# MySQL check if same value exist in another table for three times

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two MySQL tables:

```
API_Keys
+----+---------------+--------------+
| id | key_val       | Expiration |
+----+---------------+--------------+
| 1  | 111111111111  | 2018-11-13 |
+----+---------------+--------------+
| 2  | 222222222222  | 2018-11-13 |
+----+---------------+--------------+
| 3  | 333333333333  | 2018-12-13 |
+----+---------------+--------------+
| 3  | 444444444444  | 2018-11-13 |

Used_Keys
+----+------+--------------+
| id | user | key_val      |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | john | 111111111111 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 2  | sami | 111111111111 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 3  | mary | 111111111111 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 4  | nina | 333333333333 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 5  | leon | 333333333333 |
```

Each key_val can be assigned to the maximum of 3 users.
So I need to list all API_Keys table data, except the key_vals that are assigned 3 times already in Used_Keys table.

So the desired result of free API_Keys would be:

```
API_Keys
+----+---------------+--------------+
| id | key_val       | Expiration |
+----+---------------+--------------+
| 1  | 222222222222  | 2018-11-13 |
+----+---------------+--------------+
| 2  | 333333333333  | 2018-12-13 |
+----+---------------+--------------+
| 3  | 444444444444  | 2018-11-13 |
```

I would appropriate if you help me to write the MySQL select query for this purpose.

Comment: What have you tried on your own? This is not a free coding side.

Comment: Dear @BenRoob, I tried below query:

SELECT
*
FROM `API_Keys`
JOIN `Used_Keys`
ON `API_Keys`.`key_val` <> `Used_Keys`.`key_val`
HAVING `Used_Keys`.`key_val` = 3

But i didn't work and i don't know how to set that 3 time in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from api_keys as a
left join (
    select key_val 
    from Used_Keys
    group by key_val 
    having count(*) >= 3
    ) as u on a.key_val = u.key_val 
where u.key_val IS NULL
```

Comment: I Just replaced group by Used_Keys to group by key_val and It worked!
Thank you very much.

Comment: right.. ooops but you got the idea. I'll fix it too. Thanks.